# Powershell 4.0 Remoting with Non Admin Domain Account

Tags: powershell, winrm

I'm looking for help to properly configure PowerShell Remoting for non-admins on a group of servers. Right now we have a working configuration that allows Admin Domain accounts to successfully connect to the servers with no error. The authentication method we are using is **Credssp**, using **SSL** and this works perfectly for a Domain admin account.

On the other hand I have this User Domain Account **userTest**. This account is mapped to a Domain Group that maps locally (on each server) to the **Remote Desktop User Groups**. This allows for this user to RDP successfully to this server but has no administrator privileges. It is going to stay that way and it is not an option to make it Local Administrator.

The purpose of this user is to allow non-admin accounts to execute a set of scripts against the server using a **Restricted Session**, which connecting with a Domain Admin Account. The problem comes when I'm trying to connect with the **userTest** account. The server responds with a **Access is Denied** error:

`[ServerA] Connecting to remote server ServerA failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
 + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (ServerA:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken`

Going trough the Analytic EventLogs I found an error message as follows:

`The WSMan service could not launch a host process to process the given request.  Make sure the WSMan provider host server and proxy are properly registered.`

This is the configuration that I have already setup:

- Created a PSSessionConfiguration named RemoteDesktopUsers
- Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name RemoteDesktopUsers -StartupScript C:\Start.ps1
- Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name RemoteDesktopUsers -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI
  (Added **Remote Desktop Users** group to this SessionConfiguration)

So yeah, basically from what I have already Googled, this should be all the necessary configuration that you need to able to PSRemote with non-admin accounts. As I already mentioned using a Domain Admin Account connecting to this SessionConfiguration works fine, so I was thinking that I'm missing some kind of permission/privilege/SDDL that allows this user to access:

> Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
>   Powershell 4.0
>   Winrm ProductVersion = OS: 6.1.7601 SP: 1.0 Stack: 3.0

Answer (score 1):

**You're probably running into this problem because of using CredSSP**

Any particular reason you have to use CredSSP?  The most popular use of CredSSP is provided for situations in which you need to configure a jump server to remote from one machine, into another, and from there out again to another server.  It's well-known as Second-Hop funtionality and is such a huge security hole that the CredSSP is kind of a pain to configure, intentionally.

You have to configure CredSSP in three places, once on your machine from which you'll be remoting, then again on the machine you'll be jumping to, and finally on each machine you'll be connecting to from the jump server.

If you really have to use CredSSP, [follow this great guide here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx) on The Scripting Guy's blog.

**If you don't need CredSSP**

Try this whole process using Default/WSman authorization, and I bet the problems will go away.

Comment: Thanks FoxDeploy, right now we RDP to a server: "ServerDeploy" from which the scripts are hosted and then we do a hop to each server in the farm that we are targeting with the script. Do i need Creddssp for this Scenario? 

So what you are saying is to drop the Credssp configuration altogether. I´m not sure why Credssp is configured, just following what was already configured here.

Comment: Yep, you do not need credSSP. because your are rdping into that server and from there doing PS remoting that's only one hop of PowerShell remoting. However, if you from your desktop PowerShell remoted into ServerDeploy, and from there invoked all of your scripts which remote elsewhere, you would need CredSSP. The only good reason to use second hop is for super high security environments where you only allow certain groups of machines to be administered remotely by a subset of people, on a subset of machines. That's known as a jump server scenario, common in high end financial firms.

Comment: Ok i have dropped the CreddSSP by running Disable-WsManCredSSP on both Client and Server. Activiated Basic Authentication and Allowed Unencrypted Traffic on both client and server. Still using SSL on port 5986. Still getting access is Denied.

Comment: Julio, I would begin more simply.  Start with basic, unencrypted remoting and then get that working before proceeding to SSL on a custom port or other domain-specific security requirements.

Comment: I have tried that now, unencrypted(HTTP) and basic authentication (Even tough basic seems to work only for local accounts). I created a local user account and added him to the remote desktop user. This user can connect from a remote, but only after it was added to the group. Just for testing i disallowed Administrators to connect to microsoft.powershell endpoint and Remote Desktop Users to connect: Local user can connect, Domain admin cannot connect, Domain user cannot connect. So i guess there is something that i need to configure at domain level.

Comment: Can this machine contact a domain controller?

Comment: How can i tell? i can open the Active Directory Users and Computers, and connect to all the Domain Controllers

Comment: Hi Julio, try to follow the troubleshooting steps listed here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/29/remoting-week-non-domain-remoting.aspx